# Ionic build platform override

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

I have `build` platform for `android` and `ios` at starting of the app.

> I want to override android and ios build after some completion of the project.

command I'm using:

```
ionic platform build android
```

and it's giving error:

```
error: Platform "build" not recognized as as core cordova platform. See 'cordova platform list'.
```

I have tried even:

```
cordova platform build android
```

it's showing Available platforms. But `apk` file is not getting overridden.

What should I do to get a latest `apk` build output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build command is:

ionic build android

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this error but after uninstall all the **ngCordova plugin**  and reinstall all, then i got No Error.

Comment: Can you tell me little about command lines? how to uninstall or reinstall?

Comment: In your ionic project you can see the plugin folder see all the plugin you have installed then just uninstall all one by one and then re-install. That's how it worked for me without any error.